# How to wire a SessionFactory into a Hibernate Interceptor with Spring?

Tags: spring, hibernate, interceptor, sessionfactory

So, I am following the Hibernate documentation to configure interceptors ([link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/events.html#objectstate-interceptors)). Then, I am registering my interceptor in the AnnotationSessionFactoryBean as follows:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="entityInterceptor">
<bean class="domain.interceptor.AddressInterceptor"/>
</property>
</bean>
```

What I want to achieve is to insert a row in my log table when something is caught in my Interceptor. Though, this introduces a cyclical configuration dependency: the Interceptor needs the SessionFactory and the SessionFactory needs the Interceptor. How could I wire in the SessionFactory in my Interceptor?

Comment: Why are you using the `SessionFactory` directly in the `Interceptor` instead of at the DAO layer?

Comment: For simplicity of this proof of concept that I am doing. Even if I used a DAO, the circular dependency would exist.